# in struts2 jquery grid, how can we two heading rows

Tags: jquery

In jquery i want to divide heading row into tow rows.in both row saperate name can be given.

Answer (score 0):

checkout the [grid showcase](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action) for having a sub-grid. It may fulfill your requirement.

[You can also download a subgrid example project built using netbeans 6.9.](http://www.ziddu.com/downloadlink/13995815/SubGrid.rar)